# Obter valor de dentro de uma String C#

Tags: c#

Preciso pegar o valor dentro de uma string de forma dinâmica. Os valores da string serão sempre no seguinte formato:

```
Ex1: "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> Fiscal Mestre"
Ex2: "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> Analista CAU"
Ex3: "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> ESCR-PREC-PILOTO"
```

O valor que preciso é esse que inicia após o -> e finaliza antes de " ou seja:

```
Ex1: Fiscal Mestre
Ex2: Analista CAU
Ex3: ESCR-PREC-PILOTO
```

Uma observação, após **->** existe sempre um espaço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode achar o índice do `>` pelo Método `IndexOf`:

```
string valor = teste.Substring(teste.IndexOf(">")+1).Trim();
```

Ou Utilizar um Split:

```
string valor2 = teste.Split('>')[1].Trim();
```

Exemplo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string teste = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> Fiscal Mestre";

        string valor = teste.Substring(teste.IndexOf(">")+1).Trim();
        string valor2 = teste.Split('>')[1].Trim();

        Console.WriteLine("Com indexof: "+ valor);
        Console.WriteLine("Com Split: "+ valor2);
    }
}
```

> Resultado:
>
> Com IndexOf: Fiscal Mestre
>
> Com Split: Fiscal Mestre

Coloquei no DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1rOqhB

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma **BEM SIMPLES** de fazer isso é usar o [replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Ex1 = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> Fiscal Mestre"
Ex2 = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> Analista CAU"
Ex3 = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> ESCR-PREC-PILOTO"

Ex1 = Ex1.Replace("Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> ", string.Empty);
Ex2 = Ex2.Replace("Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> ", string.Empty);
Ex3 = Ex3.Replace("Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> ", string.Empty);
```