# Como fazer um split de espaço?

Tags: c#, split

eu tenho esse texto:

```
"resultados 2018 295 1 br"
```

como eu separo por espaço e coloco em strings?
exemplo:

```
string ano = argumento[0];
// iria ser 2018
string ano = argumento[1];
// iria ser 295
string ano = argumento[2];
// iria ser 1
string ano = argumento[3];
// iria ser br
```

Comment: já tem essa resposta no site

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40379/recuperar-parte-de-uma-string-split-ou-indexof

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35400/como-obter-um-trecho-de-uma-string

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279904/obter-valor-de-dentro-de-uma-string-c